# Matrix Matrix product operations OpenMDAO

Tags: matrix-multiplication, openmdao

Does openmdao or dymos have a vectroized matrix-matrix product component similar to MatrixVectorProductComp?

I would like to do a matrix multiplication of matrix A having a shape of (nn,3,3) times a matrix B having a shape of (nn,3,3), and the output being the result of shape (nn,3,3).

A 2D example of this with nn=2 could be:

```
A = np.array([[[1, 3], [0, 1]],[[-1, 7], [0, 1]]])
B = np.array([[[4, 1],  [2, 2]],[[2, 1],  [2, 3]]])

For the first node:
C[0,:,:] = np.matmul(A[0,:,:], B[0,:,:]) 
[[10  7]
 [ 2  2]]
And second Node
C[1,:,:] = np.matmul(A[1,:,:], B[1,:,:])
[[12 20]
 [ 2  3]]
```

There is a component called MatrixVectorProductComp which multiples a Matrix times a Vector with specified vector dimensions/nodes. I was trying to make an extension to the component for matrix operations using np.einsum('nij,njk->nik', A, B) and providing its partials. However, it crashes when attempting to assert_check its partial derivatives (check partials returns an empty {}):

```
nn = 5 
model = om.Group()
ivc = om.IndepVarComp()
ivc.add_output(name='A', shape=(nn, 3, 3))
ivc.add_output(name='B', shape=(nn, 3, 3))

model.add_subsystem(name='ivc',
                           subsys=ivc,
                           promotes_outputs=['A', 'B'])

model.add_subsystem(name='mat_vec_product_comp',
                      subsys=MatrixMatrixProductComp(vec_size=nn))

model.connect('A', 'mat_vec_product_comp.A')
model.connect('B', 'mat_vec_product_comp.B')

p = om.Problem(model)
p.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)

p['A'] = np.random.rand(nn, 3, 3)
p['B'] = np.random.rand(nn, 3, 3)

p.run_model()
cpd = p.check_partials(compact_print=False, method='cs')
assert_check_partials(cpd, atol=1.0E-6, rtol=1.0E-6)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/tools/OpenMDAO/openmdao/components/matrix_matrix_product_comp.py",
> line 294, in 
> assert_check_partials(cpd, atol=1.0E-6, rtol=1.0E-6)   File "c:\tools\dymos\dymos\utils\testing_utils.py", line 12, in
> assert_check_partials
> assert len(data) >= 1, "No check partials data found.  Is " \ AssertionError: No check partials data found.  Is
> dymos.options['include_check_partials'] set to True?

**MatrixMatrixProductComp code:**

```
"""Definition of the Matrix Matrix Product Component."""


import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as spla

from openmdao.core.explicitcomponent import ExplicitComponent


class MatrixMatrixProductComp(ExplicitComponent):
    """
    Computes a vectorized matrix-vector product.

    math::
        b = np.dot(A, B)

    where A is of shape (vec_size, n, m)
          B is of shape (vec_size, m,p)
          b is of shape (vec_size, n,p)

    if vec_size > 1 and

    where A is of shape (n, m)
          B is of shape (m,p)
          b is of shape (n,p)

    otherwise.

    The size of vectors x and b is determined by the number of rows in m at each point.

    Attributes
    ----------
    _products : list
        Cache the data provided during `add_product`
        so everything can be saved until setup is called.
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize the Matrix Vector Product component.

        Parameters
        ----------
        **kwargs : dict of keyword arguments
            Keyword arguments that will be mapped into the Component options.
        """
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self._products = []

        opt = self.options
        self.add_product(b_name=opt['b_name'], A_name=opt['A_name'], B_name=opt['B_name'],
                         b_units=opt['b_units'], A_units=opt['A_units'], B_units=opt['B_units'],
                         vec_size=opt['vec_size'], A_shape=opt['A_shape'], B_shape=opt['B_shape'])

        self._no_check_partials = False

    def initialize(self):
        """
        Declare options.
        """
        self.options.declare('vec_size', types=int, default=1,
                             desc='The number of points at which the matrix vector product '
                                  'is to be computed')
        self.options.declare('A_name', types=str, default='A',
                             desc='The variable name for the matrix.')
        self.options.declare('A_shape', types=tuple, default=(3, 3),
                             desc='The shape of the input matrix at a single point.')
        self.options.declare('A_units', types=str, default=None, allow_none=True,
                             desc='The units of the input matrix.')
        # self.options.declare('A_transpose', types=bool, default=False, allow_none=True,
        #                      desc='If true, matrix is transposed first')
        self.options.declare('B_name', types=str, default='B',
                             desc='The name of the input vector.')
        self.options.declare('B_shape', types=tuple, default=(3, 3),
                             desc='The shape of the input matrix at a single point.')
        self.options.declare('B_units', types=str, default=None, allow_none=True,
                             desc='The units of the input vector.')
        self.options.declare('b_name', types=str, default='b',
                             desc='The variable name of the output vector.')
        self.options.declare('b_units', types=str, default=None, allow_none=True,
                             desc='The units of the output vector.')

    def add_product(self, b_name, A_name='A', B_name='B', A_units=None, B_units=None, b_units=None,
                    vec_size=1, A_shape=(3, 3), B_shape=(3, 3)):
        """
        Add a new output product to the matrix vector product component.

        Parameters
        ----------
        A_name : str
            The name of the matrix input.
        B_name : str
            The name of the matrix input.
        b_name : str
            The name of the vector product output.
        A_units : str or None
            The units of the input matrix.
        B_units : str or None
            The units of the input matrix.
        b_units : str or None
            The units of the output matrix.
        vec_size : int
            The number of points at which the matrix vector product
            should be computed simultaneously.
        A_shape : tuple of (int, int)
            The shape of the matrix at each point.
            The first element also specifies the size of the output at each point.
            The second element specifies the size of the input vector at each point.
            For example, if vec_size=10 and shape is (5, 3), then
            the input matrix will have a shape of (10, 5, 3),
            the input vector will have a shape of (10, 3), and
            the output vector will have shape of (10, 5).
        B_shape : tuple of (int, int)
            The shape of the matrix at each point.
            The first element also specifies the size of the output at each point.
            The second element specifies the size of the input vector at each point.
            For example, if vec_size=10 and shape is (5, 3), then
            the input matrix will have a shape of (10, 5, 3),
            the input vector will have a shape of (10, 3), and
            the output vector will have shape of (10, 5).
        """
        self._products.append({
            'A_name': A_name,
            'B_name': B_name,
            'b_name': b_name,
            'A_units': A_units,
            'B_units': B_units,
            'b_units': b_units,
            'A_shape': A_shape,
            'B_shape': B_shape,
            'vec_size': vec_size
        })

        # add inputs and outputs for all products
        if self._static_mode:
            var_rel2meta = self._static_var_rel2meta
            var_rel_names = self._static_var_rel_names
        else:
            var_rel2meta = self._var_rel2meta
            var_rel_names = self._var_rel_names

        n_rows_A, n_cols_A = A_shape
        n_rows_B, n_cols_B = B_shape

        A_shape = (vec_size, n_rows_A, n_cols_A)
        B_shape = (vec_size, n_rows_B, n_cols_B)
        b_shape = (vec_size, n_rows_A, n_cols_B) if vec_size > 1 else (n_rows_A, n_cols_B)

        if b_name not in var_rel2meta:
            self.add_output(name=b_name, shape=b_shape, units=b_units)
        elif b_name in var_rel_names['input']:
            raise NameError(f"{self.msginfo}: '{b_name}' specified as an output, "
                            "but it has already been defined as an input.")
        else:
            raise NameError(f"{self.msginfo}: Multiple definition of output '{b_name}'.")

        if A_name not in var_rel2meta:
            self.add_input(name=A_name, shape=A_shape, units=A_units)
        elif A_name in var_rel_names['output']:
            raise NameError(f"{self.msginfo}: '{A_name}' specified as an input, "
                            "but it has already been defined as an output.")
        else:
            meta = var_rel2meta[A_name]
            if vec_size != meta['shape'][0]:
                raise ValueError(f"{self.msginfo}: Conflicting vec_size={B_shape[0]} "
                                 f"specified for matrix '{A_name}', which has already "
                                 f"been defined with vec_size={meta['shape'][0]}.")

            elif (n_rows_A, n_cols_A) != meta['shape'][1:]:
                raise ValueError(f"{self.msginfo}: Conflicting shape {A_shape[1:]} specified "
                                 f"for matrix '{A_name}', which has already been defined "
                                 f"with shape {meta['shape'][1:]}.")

            elif A_units != meta['units']:
                raise ValueError(f"{self.msginfo}: Conflicting units '{A_units}' specified "
                                 f"for matrix '{A_name}', which has already been defined "
                                 f"with units '{meta['units']}'.")

        if B_name not in var_rel2meta:
            self.add_input(name=B_name, shape=B_shape, units=B_units)
        elif B_name in var_rel_names['output']:
            raise NameError(f"{self.msginfo}: '{B_name}' specified as an input, "
                            "but it has already been defined as an output.")
        else:
            meta = var_rel2meta[B_name]
            if vec_size != meta['shape'][0]:
                raise ValueError(f"{self.msginfo}: Conflicting vec_size={B_shape[0]} "
                                 f"specified for vector '{B_name}', which has already "
                                 f"been defined with vec_size={meta['shape'][0]}.")

            elif n_cols_A != meta['shape'][1]:
                raise ValueError(f"{self.msginfo}: Matrix shape {A_shape[1:]} is incompatible "
                                 f"with vector '{B_name}', which has already been defined "
                                 f"with {meta['shape'][1]} column(s).")

            elif B_units != meta['units']:
                raise ValueError(f"{self.msginfo}: Bonflicting units '{B_units}' specified "
                                 f"for vector '{B_name}', which has already been defined "
                                 f"with units '{meta['units']}'.")

        # Make a dummy version of A so we can figure out the nonzero indices
        A = np.ones(A_shape)
        B = np.ones(B_shape)
        # print(A.shape)
        bd_A = spla.block_diag(*A)
        # print(bd_A.shape)
        bd_B = spla.block_diag(*B)
        B_repeat = np.repeat(B, A.shape[1], axis=0)
        A_repeat = np.repeat(A, B.shape[1], axis=0)
        # print(A_repeat.shape)
        bd_B_repeat = spla.block_diag(*B_repeat)
        bd_A_repeat = spla.block_diag(*A_repeat)
        # print(bd_A_repeat.shape)
        db_dB_rows, db_dB_cols = np.nonzero(bd_A_repeat)
        db_dA_rows, db_dA_cols = np.nonzero(bd_B_repeat)

        # db_dA_rows = np.arange()
        self.declare_partials(of=b_name, wrt=A_name,
                              rows=db_dA_rows, cols=db_dA_cols)
        self.declare_partials(of=b_name, wrt=B_name,
                              rows=db_dB_rows, cols=db_dB_cols)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        """
        Compute the matrix vector product of inputs `A` and `x` using np.einsum.

        Parameters
        ----------
        inputs : Vector
            unscaled, dimensional input variables read via inputs[key]
        outputs : Vector
            unscaled, dimensional output variables read via outputs[key]
        """
        for product in self._products:
            A = inputs[product['A_name']]
            B = inputs[product['B_name']]
            outputs[product['b_name']][...] = np.einsum('nij,njk->nik', A, B)

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, partials):
        """
        Compute the sparse partials for the matrix vector product w.r.t. the inputs.

        Parameters
        ----------
        inputs : Vector
            unscaled, dimensional input variables read via inputs[key]
        partials : Jacobian
            sub-jac components written to partials[output_name, input_name]
        """
        for product in self._products:
            A_name = product['A_name']
            B_name = product['B_name']
            b_name = product['b_name']

            A = inputs[A_name]
            B = inputs[B_name]

            # Use the following for sparse partials
            partials[b_name, A_name] = np.repeat(B, A.shape[1], axis=0).ravel()
            partials[b_name, B_name] = np.repeat(A, B.shape[1], axis=0).ravel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import openmdao.api as om
    import dymos as dm
    from openmdao.utils.assert_utils import assert_near_equal
    from dymos.utils.testing_utils import assert_check_partials

    nn = 5

    model = om.Group()
    ivc = om.IndepVarComp()
    ivc.add_output(name='A', shape=(nn, 3, 3))
    ivc.add_output(name='B', shape=(nn, 3, 3))

    model.add_subsystem(name='ivc',
                               subsys=ivc,
                               promotes_outputs=['A', 'B'])

    model.add_subsystem(name='MatrixMatrixProductComp',
                          subsys=MatrixMatrixProductComp(vec_size=nn))

    model.connect('A', 'MatrixMatrixProductComp.A')
    model.connect('B', 'MatrixMatrixProductComp.B')

    p = om.Problem(model)
    p.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)

    p['A'] = np.random.rand(nn, 3, 3)
    p['B'] = np.random.rand(nn, 3, 3)

    p.run_model()
    cpd = p.check_partials(compact_print=False, method='cs')
    assert_check_partials(cpd, atol=1.0E-6, rtol=1.0E-6)
```

Comment: your question is a bit vauge. Im not sure what you mean by vectorized matrix-matrix product. Are you asking if you can multiple two matricies? or is there an extra dimention in one of inputs so you're multiplying a vector of matricies by another matrix (or vector of matricies)? Could you please include at least a numpy example of the kind of product you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi justin. My apologies for the original formulation. i edited it with an example. I was creating also a sort of component to deal with it but was having issues when verifying its partials (included the issue), so i was wondering if maybe there was already a component which does this and i missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the code to your `MatrixMatrixProductComp`, but I can make an educated guess as to whats going on because you referenced the [`MatrixVectorProductComp`](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.10.0/features/building_blocks/components/matrix_vector_product_comp.html) in OpenMDAO's standard library.

For all components in OpenMDAO's standard library, the developers have already implemented and verified the derivatives. Thus, there is no need to have those components show up in the output of `check_partials` for 99.9999% of the time. It would just clutter up the output that users need to see.

There is a hidden, undocumented, flag `_no_check_partials` that gets turned on in these components so that `check_partials` skips them. Now that I have blabbed about this hidden flag all over the internet :) ... [here is where its assigned in the MatrixVectorProductComp](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/aa7c8f2e29809c4ccd1832f902fa0baee2c57d93/openmdao/components/matrix_vector_product_comp.py#L56)
The Dymos library used this feature too, so that Dymos components didn't clutter up user check_partials outputs for their ODE components and groups.

Again, Dymos did this because those partials have already been carefully verified! Also there is s[pecial code in Dymos that flips that flag off](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/blob/master/dymos/transcriptions/pseudospectral/components/gauss_lobatto_interleave_comp.py#L23) so that internal tests can verify Dymos component partials.

Most likely you just need to set that attribute to False, and you'll get some check_partials output you can use in a test. I am being careful to emphasize that this flag should only be used with great caution. Bad partials will break an optimization, and if you have that flag turned on then you may simply never get a report of that component in check_partials.

In your case, you got burned by having no other components in your model, so you got the empty dictionary error. Generally, I do not recommend any user code use this flag at all.

Comment: Hi Justin, thank you for pointing it out! I was able to check the partials, and as expected I didnt provide them correctly. Making a shortcut to it (just deriving the matrix multiplications i need analytically for now) and will maybe address it at later stages. 

In case its useful for someone, i addded it in the initial post, but note that the compute_partials routines are not working correctly.